# A C# app that references a C# dll which uses Enterprise Library is throwing an error

Tags: c#, .net, enterprise-library

I have a C# app that references another C# dll which in turn uses Enterprise Library. 
Because my app has no config xml file for setting the Enterprise Library settings, it is throwing an error, specifically:

```
"The configuration section for Logging cannot be found in the configuration source."
"Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging"
```

I would rather not add an XML config file to my app to just turn off Enterprise Library. 
Is there a code way to do so in my the source for my app?

**EDIT:**

I'm on EL 4.1

Comment: Does the C# dll that uses Enterprise Library come with a configuration file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have details for the exact configuration you are looking for, but Enterprise Library 5 has a [fluent configuration API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.common.configuration.fluent%28PandP.50%29.aspx) you can use.

As far as I know, previous versions can only be configured via XML files.

Comment: you can use the configurationSource option to have it's configuration in another xml file than the main config file...

Comment: @Tim Mahy - But you still need at least one config file. The OP doesn't want _any_ configuration files.

Comment: You *can* programmatically configure Enterprise Library logging but you need to use the objects that you create directly -- you cannot just globally say to use this configuration information that was created programmatically.